# What would be the worst case run time of my algorithm

Tags: python

So I know that my algorithm is in O(n) runtime because it only has to loop through the list once, but I have no clue how to calculate the worst case run time. Would it still be linear because it is looping no matter what?

```
 def find_duplicates(lst):
    duplist = []

    for i in range(0, len(lst)):

        if abs(lst[i]) == len(lst):
            element = -1
        else:
            element = lst[abs(lst[i])]
        if element > 0:
            lst[abs(lst[i])] = -lst[abs(lst[i])]
        elif element == 0:
            lst[abs(lst[i])] = -len(lst)
        else:
            if abs(lst[i]) == len(lst):
                duplist.append(0)
            else:
                duplist.append(abs(lst[i]))

    return duplist
```

Comment: yes it is linear worst case, because you must FINISH looping over the list to solve the problem in this way. There is no case in which you would not finish the loop, so worst case and best case are the same here.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it will indeed be O(n). In worst case, all of your if's will fail and the last statement of every if block will be executed. So, every iteration executes 6 statements. Still then, your time complexity will be O(6n) which is still O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the worst, as well as the best and the average, time complexity of this function is *O(n)*, since it iterates for exactly the same number of times as the size of the input list no matter which conditions are met, with no additional iterations nested inside.